# Динамическое создание списка ссылок на комментарии по хештегам

Tags: javascript, ссылки, список, комментарии

Здравствуйте не особо понимаю язык javascript но может кто нибудь помочь есть задача искать текст в комментариях по тегам и формировать список из ссылок на комментарии с определенным текстом после хештега например :

```
<div class="menushka">Сюда должен попадать список из совпадений</div>

Комментарии:
<div class="message">какой то текст #ТЕГ:Заголовок для списка ссылок@ идет далее какой то текст <a id="pipi" href="index.php#3"></a></div>
<div class="message">Совсем другой какой то то текст #ТЕГ: Совсем другой Заголовок для списка ссылок@ идет далее какой то текст<a id="pipi" href="index.php#3"></a></div>
<div class="message">здесь вообще нет тегов и какой то текст <a id="pipi" href="index.php#3"></a></div>
```

Скрипт который написал он работает но находит только первое совпадение добавляет ссылку только на первый комментарий а дальше не ищет совпадения

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
var descript = document.getElementsByClassName('message'); 
var tests= descript[i].innerText; 
var note= tests.search('@'); 
var rote= tests.search('#ТЕГ'); 
var newstr = tests.substring(rote,note); 
if (rote > 1){ 
var red = document.getElementById("pipi"); 
var attribute = red.getAttribute("href"); 
var reds= attribute.innerText; 
$('.menushka').append('<a href="'+attribute+'">'+newstr+'</a>'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо заменить tests.search на test.match

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на SO. Вопрос задали очень давно, так что скорей всего автор вам не ответит. Свежие вопросы по JS есть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest